# ember shortcut for packing up all the properties of a model object into a post or put

Tags: ember.js

I am just starting with ember and am not using ember data. I have some code liek this:

```
Hex.Location = Ember.Object.extend({
    id: null,
    name:null,
    city:null,
    state:null,
    zip_code:null,
    is_enabled:null,
    tag_line:null,
    longitude:null,
    latitude:null,
    create: function(){
        return Ember.$.post( "/arc/v1/api/locations", {name: this.name, website: this.website, latitude:this.latitude, longitude: this.longitude, street: this.street, city: this.city,
            state:this.state, zip_code:this.zip_code, is_enabled: this.is_enabled, is_launch_set: this.is_launch_set, phone:this.phone });// , function(data ) {
```

But this obviously seems very wasteful in terms of typing all of the properties out. Is there a shortcut? I have named everything the same as it should be on the wire and in my Javascript objects?

thx

Answer (score 0):

You can call

```
this.getProperties('name', 'city', 'state', 'zip_code', 'is_enabled', 'tag_line', 'longitude', 'latitude')
```

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Object.html#method_getProperties

But I don't think there is a shortcut to get **all** the properties in the object.